# MySQL with more rows loads longer but its run with limit

Tags: mysql

i have this Problem.
To make a lower loading time, i want to get only 30 Items from my table. It works, but it loads longer time when there much items on the table.

But why? I only want to get 30 Items, not everything and setup the Offset when going to next Page.

Here is my SELECT query

```
SELECT * 
FROM bank 
WHERE withdraw = 0 
ORDER BY CAST(item_price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC 
LIMIT 30 OFFSET (+page)
```

can someone explain me how to make it faster?
That +page is the offset with javascript, it works

I change the query a little bit, but doesnt help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM bank 
WHERE withdraw = 0 
ORDER BY item_price DESC 
LIMIT 30 OFFSET (+page)
```

// new

if i change that to that query, it loads the same time but on 350 rows? Why?

```
SELECT * 
FROM bank 
WHERE withdraw = 0
```

Comment: there is no Offset value set in your query. Also ORDER BY makes it slow. Is CASTing necessary ? Give your EXPLAIN statement result

Comment: its only a simple table with item_name, item_price and ID increment. I will ORDER BY highest Price, thats all. The Offset ist loading by javascript variable. Its working

Comment: how many rows  have your bank table ?  .. rememeber that  limit 30 mean that you are show  only 30 rows  of entire select

Comment: There 350 Rows, but there will be much more soon. Its in testing now but its already loading to long. I only want to get 30 rows to make it faster, but its not faster :/

Comment: Is there an index on `withdraw`?

Comment: and what mean (+page)  .. try using a fixed  value for test  eg_ OFFSET 30

Comment: scaisEdge, i tried a simple query, look my post please, that loads the same time like that before with limit

Comment: If I give you a phone book and tell you: please give me the first 30 entries, ordered by the phone number. How long does it take you? This is basically what you are asking MySQL to do. What would you need to make it faster?

Comment: Markus W Mahlberg `withdraw` is `int(1)` and default = 0 or you mean i must run `ALTER TABLE bank ADD INDEX('withdraw')`?

Comment: Solarflare sure, but its loading the same time if i say give me all rows or same time without `ORDER BY`

Comment: how many seconds  the query run???

Comment: scaisEdge, 5.84s without `ORDER BY`, without `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` and 5.45s with `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`

I mean that doesnt change anything...

Comment: Okay i think its another problem in my system, not mysql. Sorry guys :(

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset